# SSD не даёт BIOS запуститься

Tags: windows-7, bios, ssd, asus

У меня возникла проблема: купив SSD, я поставил на неё Windows 7. Установка прошла нормально, однако после появления рабочего стола ОС внезапно перезагрузил ась и дальше логотипа ноутбука не идёт. После любой попытки перезагрузить компьютер, ОС не запускается, как и BIOS. Но после извлечения диска из ноутбука, BIOS запускается.
В чём могут быть причины подобной ерунды?
Ноутбук ASUS K501UX, диск подключён к SATA.
В BIOS я менял конфигурацию SATA на AHCI, включил параметр *launch csm*

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас отображается логотип, то BIOS стартует нормально. Скорее всего Вы хотели сказать, что операционная система не загружается.
Проблема скорее всего в том, что при установке системы SATA Mode был установлен в IDE, а после установки Вы его поменяли на AHCI.
Смените режим на IDE или переустановите систему с SATA Mode AHCI.

Comment: Большое спасибо за рекомендацию, но я смог решить проблему другим путём. Я вытащил диск, из-за которого возникла проблема, прошил BIOS до новой версии и всё заработало